# Is it safe to use boost::asio::strand in this way?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++17

Said I have a worker class

```
class MyWorker : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyWorker> {
public:
    MyWorker(boost::asio::io_service& ioService) : strand_(ioService) {}

    void Work(int n) {
        strand_.post([weak_this = weak_from_this(), n]() {
            printf("work %d run from strand\n", n);
            if (auto ptr = weak_this.lock()) ptr->DoWork(n);
        });
    }

    void DoWork(int n) {
        n_ = n;
        printf("work %d done\n", n);
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service::strand strand_;
    int n_;
};
```

Anyone can post works to a worker object, and it will be en-queued and do work in sequence. When I want to stop a worker object, I can just un-reference shared _ptr. Pending work will not call into object (protected by weak_ptr)

Here is example scenario

```
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    auto worker = std::make_shared<MyWorker>(ioService);

    ioService.post([] () { printf("other work 1\n"); });
    worker->Work(1);
    ioService.post([] () { printf("other work 2\n"); });
    worker->Work(2);

    worker.reset(); // <- strand_ destroyed after this line

    ioService.run();
    return 0;
}
```

This exmaple can run without crash. The output is

```
other work 1
work 1 run from strand
other work 2
work 2 run from strand
```

No "work 1 done", "work 2 done" which is expected.

But at the time I called io_service::run(), strand is already destroyed. Is this safe? Or something undefined behavior may happened?

Comment: Looks fine to me (much easier to see if you imagine `MyWorker::Work` as a free function). It _does_ assume that it's okay to have wrapped handlers even after the `strand` object is destroyed. I **think** that is okay, but I'd need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I almost forgot about this question since my comment:

> Looks fine to me (much easier to see if you imagine MyWorker::Work as a free function). It does assume that it's okay to have wrapped handlers even after the strand object is destroyed. I think that is okay, but I'd need to check.

I did have a look at the implementation and indeed the implementation of the strand service is such that it is safe to have handlers associated with them after destructing the `strand` instance.

That makes your code fine.